# DBeaver / PostgreSQL: "Error: database already exists", but I can't find it

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, create-table, dbeaver

I want to create database called "President" by rightclicking on *PostgreSQL* and selecting *Create Database*.

However, I get the error in the screenprint below.

I can create databases with other names like *SomeOtherDatabase* and *SomeOtherDatabase2* (see screenprints).

Any ideas how I can find and delete the database "President" that seems to exist already?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE!!**

If I execute

```
select * from pg_database
```

I get the following result:

[image]

So database "President" does seem to exist. (Meanwhile I deleted *someOtherDatabase* and *someOtherDatabase2*.)

However, if I execute

```
drop database President
```

I get:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query [catalog view `pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-database.html) to check if the database already exists:

```
select datname from pg_database WHERE datname = 'president'
```

And drop it with `drop database`:

```
drop database president;
```

Note that Postgres' `drop database` syntax supports the `if exists` clause, which may come handy in your use case:

```
drop database if exists president;
```

Comment: Thanks. The database does seem to exist because "select datname from pg_database WHERE datname = 'President'" returns "President". But "drop database President" returns "SQL Error [3D000]: ERROR: database "president" does not exist"..

Comment: @Frank: you created your database with double quotes, so the name is [case sensitive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) now. You need to use `drop database "President"`. And you should [avoid double quoted identifiers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) in the future

Comment: @– a_horse_with_no_name, It worked!! Thanks a lot :-) I was completely puzzled and this is definitely useful to know.

Answer (score 51):

You can right click on the `postgres` database and select `edit connection` option. Under the PostgreSQL tab, check the `Show all databases` option.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be the default?

Comment: Jesus christ! spent 2 hours trying to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: So much thank you on this! Spent at least an hour trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 22):

### 2023 Update

1. Right-click on your connection
2. Click "Edit connection"
3. Left panel, click "Connection settings"
4. Select PostgreSQL tab Check the box "Show all databases"

[image]

[image]